# Can i upload my website folder like this (nested folders inside main folder)?

Tags: html, web, web-folders

The image describes the main website folder that contains nested files and folders of website can i place like this ?

[image: can i place like this ?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can even put other folders inside the sub-folder. If you are using this for a navigation bar or whatever, when making links, use:

```
/subfolder/page12345.html
```

and not:

```
https://mysite/subfolder/pag12345.html
```

you can use both but he first option gives cleaner code.